# Tomcat not displaying Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm using the Sysdeo plugin to connect Eclipse (Gallileo) to Tomcat 6.0.  When I deploy a new project I can see the project.xml file in Tomcat 6.0\conf\Catalina\localhost directory.  But somehow Tomcat is not seeing this information because when I point my browser at http://localhost:8080/project I get a message that the requested resource is unavailable.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse (the EE version atleast) comes with builtin support for developing with Tomcat, I suggest you use that instead of the Sysdeo plugin - which seems to be a few years outdated by now.

Get started by creating a new "Dynamic Web Project", you'll get to point Eclipse to a local Tomcat installation - and you'll get options to Run/Debug/etc. your application on Tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

In order for Tomcat to display your project, you need to compile your project into a .war file and drop it in Tomcat's deploy/ directory.